# Question about the use of Var. in different species

Tags: taxonomy

I just recently started studying Taxonomy and seem that I am the only one that got such question in the Internet...so pardon if this is a silly question...and my silly grammar because it is not my first language.

After genus we have species, sometimes subspecies and variety. For example, the Full Red Albino Guppy breed is named *Poecilia reticulata var. "Full Red Albino"* because it is one of the variety of guppies. But I was soon confused when it comes to succulents and dogs/cats.

1. *Echeveria elegans 'Alba'* is one of the variety of *Encheveria elegans*, why it is named so with the '' marks instead of *Echeveria elegans var. "Alba"*?
2. Dalmatians/Maine Coon are a breed of dog/cat under *Canis familiaris*/*Felis catus*, so they are actually varieties of the subspecies/species but I never see anyone naming them as *Canis lupus familiaris var. "Dalmatian"*/*Felis catus var. "Maine Coon"*?

I know there is no point of naming them so but I am just curious about if this is scientifically correct or I got the wrong concept. Thanks for reading till here.